# Fermat-like equation

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for information on this kind of reverse-Fermat problem: Given $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$, find a $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $a^z + b^z = c^z$?

When does such a $z$ exist? Is anything known? Thanks.

Comment: Given arbitrary $a$, $z\in{\mathbb C}$ the expression $a^z$ is not well defined.

Comment: Sure, but it takes on a discrete set of values, and it's still reasonable to ask if we can find such a $z$ so as to make the equality hold for an appropriate choice of branches.